# Get the frequency(count) of items in a nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, counter, nested-lists

I am trying to get all the frequency of all the items in numerous lists nested in a list.
I really do not know how to go about it as I am relatively new to python.

The list:

```
Data = [['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c', 'a'], ['h', 'y', 'g'], ['a', 'c', 'y', 'b'], ['a', 'h']]
```

The expected output:

```
a = 4
b = 3
c = 2
g = 1
h = 2
y = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for this

```py
from collections import Counter

c = Counter()

for d in Data:
    # update the counter with the frequencies
    # of each sub-list
    c.update(d)

# get the value, count pairs from the counter
for k, v in c.items():
    # print them using a formatted string
    print(f'{k} = {v}')

a = 4
b = 3
c = 2
h = 2
y = 2
g = 1
```

## Edit

To show how to do this with a normal dictionary

```py
counts = {} # initialize your dictionary

for d in Data:
    for value in d:
        # using dict.get returns the value if it's there
        # or a default value if it isn't
        counts[value] = counts.get(value, 0) + 1


for k, v in counts.items():
    print(f'{k} = {v}')

a = 4
b = 3
c = 2
h = 2
y = 2
g = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

Data = [['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c', 'a'], ['h', 'y', 'g'], ['a', 'c', 'y', 'b'], ['a', 'h']]

print(dict(Counter(chain.from_iterable(Data))))
```

Output:

```
{'a': 4, 'b': 3, 'c': 2, 'h': 2, 'y': 2, 'g': 1}
```

References:
[chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)
[Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use pandas for that:

```
import pandas as pd
Data = [['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c', 'a'], ['h', 'y', 'g'], ['a', 'c', 'y', 'b'], ['a', 'h']]
pd.Series([d for sub in Data for d in sub]).value_counts()
```

output:

```
a    4
b    3
c    2
h    2
y    2
g    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).